# Regression model with GARCH (1, 1) error term

Tags: time-series, garch, finance

I am attempting to analyze the relationship between exchange rates and stock market prices using the regression model below.

What software package can I use to achieve this? How would I get the variables $a, \beta_1$ and $\varepsilon_t$?

Model: bivariate regression model with GARCH (1, 1) error term ($\varepsilon_t$):

$$\log (EX_t) = a + \beta_1 \log (SP_t) + \varepsilon_t.$$

The level exchange rate series is denoted by $EX$ and first difference data for $EX$ (denoted $EX_1$) is equal to $\log (EX_t/EX_{t-1})$. Level stock price series is denoted by $SP$ and first difference data for $SP$ (denoted $SP_1$) is equal to $\log (SP_t/SP_{t-1})$.

Comment: Try "rugarch" package for R. It allows specifying an ARMA-GARCH model with exogenous regressors in both the conditional mean and the conditional variance equations. You will need to select ARMA order of (0,0) and specify $\log(SP_t)$ as exogenous regressor in the conditional mean. Use functions `ugarchspec` for model specification and then `ugarchfit` for model estimation. Note that your variable will likely be integrated, which is why you will need to use first differences instead of levels (I do not expect them to be cointegrated, but that would require including an error correction term).

Comment: Also, consider whether $SP_t$ might be endogenous. If so, you will have the endogeneity bias, yielding biased and inconsistent estimates.

Comment: I have used the commands below as an example in R. I am very new to R. how do I extract the variables a and ß1 for the model that best fits?

Comment: Step1:  
require(rugarch)
Step2: 
data <- cbind(rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000))
Step3: 
spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
+ submodel = NULL, external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = FALSE), 
+ mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), external.regressors = matrix(data[,2]), 
+ distribution.model = "norm", start.pars = list(), fixed.pars = list()))
Step4:
garch <- ugarchfit(spec=spec,data=data[,1],solver.control=list(trace=0))

Comment: Check the so-called "methods" applicable for the class of output that is generated by `ugarchfit`; they will be listed under that class in the package manual. Also try `slotNames(garch)` to see what is inside the fitted object. The slots can be accessed by `garch@slotname`. Further inside you might need the `$` operator to extract elements of the slots, such as `garch@slotname$elementname`, something like that. Element names are found by `names(garch@slotname)`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Richard. I have used the coef function for parameter estimates.
mu        mxreg1         omega        alpha1         beta1 
-2.279839e-02 -4.334646e-02  1.052622e-03  1.090557e-08  9.989997e-01
how does this relate to my model? do you know what these variables mean?

Comment: `mu` is the intercept in the conditional mean model. `mxreg` is the regressor that was included as exogenous in the conditional mean model. That is what you are interested in. `omega` (intercept), `alpha1` ("ARCH term") and `beta1` ("GARCH" term) are the GARCH parameters.

Comment: How is the progress? Did you get what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

Try "rugarch" package for R. It allows specifying an ARMA-GARCH model with exogenous regressors in both the conditional mean and the conditional variance equations. You will need to select ARMA order of (0,0) and specify $\log(SP_t)$ as an exogenous regressor in the conditional mean. Use functions `ugarchspec` for model specification and then `ugarchfit` for model estimation. Something like:

```
spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), external.regressors = cbind(log(SP)))
fit = ugarchfit(spec=spec, data=log(EX))
```

Note that your variables will likely be integrated, which is why you will need to use first differences instead of levels (I do not expect them to be cointegrated, in which case you might need to include an error correction term in the equation). Thus something like:

```
spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), external.regressors = cbind(diff(log(SP))))
fit = ugarchfit(spec=spec, data=diff(log(EX)))
```

Also, consider whether $\log(SP_t)$ might be endogenous. If so, you will have the endogeneity bias, yielding biased and inconsistent estimates of $\beta_1$. Moreover, consider whether the effect of $\log(SP)$ on $\log(EX)$ might have a time lag.

Answer (score 1):

[Richard Hardy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/53690/richard-hardy) has already given a good answer to your question.  I am going to supplement this answer by giving some (unsolicited) advice on better framing of your problem.  I hope this is helpful to you in presenting your model form more clearly.

---

At the moment **your notation is no good** - you are using the notation $EX_\text{subscript}$ to refer to two conflicting things.  You denote the exchange rate values as $EX_t$, but you also use this notation for the first difference $EX_1 = EX_t/EX_{t-1}$.  So as it stands, the notation $EX_1$ apparently refers both to the exchange rate value at time $t=1$, and contrarily, also to the first difference $EX_t/EX_{t-1}$ at an arbitrary time that is not specified in the notation.  The same problem occurs for $SP_1$.

To fix this, you should choose different notation for your differences; the standard notational convention is to use the $\Delta$ symbol as a difference operator.  With this notation you would write $\Delta \log EX_t = \log (EX_t / EX_{t-1})$ and $\Delta \log SP_t = \log (SP_t / SP_{t-1})$.  Notice that this notation differentiates the first differences from the original series values, and it also keeps an explicit subscript reference to the time where the first difference is measured.  Now, given that your model is not framed in terms of differences, you probably don't need to mention these at all for the purposes of your question, but if you are going to do so, you should adopt better notation.

Comment: First difference of $x_t$ is normaly understood as $x_t-x_{t-1}$, not $\frac{x_t}{x_{t-1}}$, so the notation you are proposing is nonstandard. I see the OP is using it in a nonstandard way, too. I think it would be best to stick to standard terms.

Comment: Good point (+1) - I have edited to add the logarithms, which fixes this.  Thanks for catching that.